# Photo contest plugin

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

Consider this [template](http://themeforest.net/item/folio-two-portfolio-for-creative-professionals/full_screen_preview/304231)

I would like to build a similar site looking site which allows users to register and upload their images.

Each image should have title and short description, provided by the uploader, and be immeaditely available on the site once upload is complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you left something out? What does this have to do with a contest? Also: a plugin for what? You've tagged this "cms" but don't specify which you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/), you can easily buy [similar looking themes](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress/creative/portfolio) for it on theme forest, it's well supported and pretty easy to configure.

You can use custom fields and custom post types to achieve this functionality. Or try plug-ins such as [Photosmash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/) and [User Submitted Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-submitted-posts/) - both of which offer the functionality you describe with minimal configuration.